# Create deep Nested JSON using PySpark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to create a nested json file from dataframe. But I cannot convert it to Pandas. And array the value should not duplicate.

Sample data:

```
|PROD_ID|PROD_NAME|USAGE         |TYPE_PROD    |PART_ID|MATERIAL    |GRADE|MACHINE_NAME|DATE_TIME |PROCESS |LENGTH_S|WIDTH|LOCATION_ON_TOOL|PROCESS_NAME|MATERIAL_TEMPERATURE|
+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+-------+------------+-----+------------+----------+--------+--------+-----+----------------+------------+--------------------+
|1      |SHOE     |TO WALK AROUND|DAILY TRAINER|AA     |CARBON PLATE|A    |ABC123      |2020-05-28|ROLLING |17      |10   |[-1, -1]        |ROLLING     |201                 |
|1      |SHOE     |TO WALK AROUND|DAILY TRAINER|AA     |CARBON PLATE|A    |ABC123      |2020-05-28|STAMPING|17      |10   |[20, 3]         |STAMPING    |301                 |
|1      |SHOE     |TO WALK AROUND|DAILY TRAINER|AA     |CARBON PLATE|A    |ABC123      |2020-05-28|CASTING |17      |10   |[20, 3]         |CASTING     |900                 |
|1      |SHOE     |TO WALK AROUND|DAILY TRAINER|AA     |CARBON PLATE|A    |ABC123      |2020-05-28|CASTING |17      |10   |[20, 3]         |CASTING     |532                 |
|1      |SHOE     |TO WALK AROUND|DAILY TRAINER|AA     |CARBON PLATE|A    |ABC123      |2020-05-28|CASTING |17      |10   |[90, 100]       |CASTING     |532                 |
+-------+---------+--------------+-------------+-------+------------+-----+------------+----------+--------+--------+-----+----------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Output Expectation:

```
{
    "PRODS": {
        "Prod_ID": "1",
        "Prod_Name": "SHOE",
        "Usage": "TO_WALK_AROUND",
        "PARTS": [
            {
                "Part_ID":"AA",
                "Material":"CARBON PLATE",
                "Grade":"A",
                "MANUFACTURE": [
                    {
                        "Machine_Name": "ABC123",
                        "Date_Time": "2020-05-28",
                        "Process": "Rolling"
                    },
                    {
                        "Machine_Name": "ABC123",
                        "Date_Time": "2020-05-28",
                        "Process": "Stamping"
                    },
                    {
                        "Machine_Name": "ABC123",
                        "Date_Time": "2020-05-28",
                        "Process": "Casting"
                    }
                ],
                "DIMENSION": [
                    {
                        "Length":17,
                        "Width": 10,
                    }
                ],
                "PARAMETER": [
                    {
                        "Location_On_Tool": [-1,-1],
                        "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                            {
                                "Process_Name": "Rolling",
                                "Material_Temperature": [201]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Location_On_Tool": [20,3],
                        "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                            {
                                "Process_Name": "Stamping",
                                "Material_Temperature": [301]
                            }.
                            {
                                "Process_Name": "Casting",
                                "Material_Temperature": [532,900]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Location_On_Tool": [90,100],
                        "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                            {
                                "Process_Name": "Casting",
                                "Material_Temperature": [532]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see in the json file, array in `MANUFACTURE`, value for `Machine_Name and Date_Time` is same but since the `Process` is different, it will create another element in array. Same goes in `PARAMETER` array.

I tried `collect_list, struct, agg, groupBy` but still didn't get the exact json as I want.

P/s: Later I'll post my code that didn't work.

Updated: My code that didn't work without `MANUFACTURE` key

```
grouped_data_1=df.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD', 'PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','MACHINE_NAME','DATE_TIME','PROCESS','LENGTH_S','WIDTH', 'LOCATION_ON_TOOL','PROCESS_NAME').agg(collect_set('MATERIAL_TEMPERATURE').alias('MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE'))

grouped_data_2=grouped_data_1.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD', 'PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','MACHINE_NAME','DATE_TIME','PROCESS','LENGTH_S','WIDTH', 'LOCATION_ON_TOOL').agg(collect_set(struct('PROCESS_NAME','MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE')).alias('MEASUREMENT_DATA'))

grouped_data_3=grouped_data_2.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD', 'PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','MACHINE_NAME','DATE_TIME','PROCESS','LENGTH_S','WIDTH').agg(collect_set(struct('MEASUREMENT_DATA', 'LOCATION_ON_TOOL')).alias('PARAMETER'))

grouped_data_4=grouped_data_3.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD', 'PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','MACHINE_NAME','DATE_TIME','PROCESS').agg(collect_set(struct('LENGTH_S','WIDTH')).alias('DIMENSION'))

join_grouped_data=grouped_data_3.join(grouped_data_4,['PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD', 'PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','MACHINE_NAME','DATE_TIME','PROCESS']).select(grouped_data_3.PROD_ID,grouped_data_3.PROD_NAME,grouped_data_3.USAGE,grouped_data_3.TYPE_PROD,grouped_data_3.PART_ID,grouped_data_3.MATERIAL,grouped_data_3.GRADE,grouped_data_3.PROCESS,grouped_data_3.MACHINE_NAME,grouped_data_3.PROCESS,grouped_data_3.PARAMETER,grouped_data_4.DIMENSION )

grouped_data_4=join_grouped_data.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD').agg(collect_set(struct('PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','PARAMETER','DIMENSION')).alias('PARTS'))

nested_json=grouped_data_4.withColumn('nested_json', to_json(struct('PARTS')))
```

The problem with the code is after join, it will have duplicate `PARAMETER and DIMENSION`
Output from the code

```
{
    "PARTS": [
        {
            "PART_ID": "AA",
            "MATERIAL": "CARBON PLATE",
            "GRADE": "A",
            "DIMENSION": [
                {
                    "LENGTH_S": 17,
                    "WIDTH": 10
                }
            ],
            "PARAMETER": [
                {
                    "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                        {
                            "PROCESS_NAME": "ROLLING",
                            "MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE": [201]
                        }
                    ],
                    "LOCATION_ON_TOOL": [-1,-1]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PART_ID": "AA",
            "MATERIAL": "CARBON PLATE",
            "GRADE": "A",
            "DIMENSION": [
                {
                    "LENGTH_S": 17,
                    "WIDTH": 10
                }
            ],
            "PARAMETER": [
                {
                    "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                        {
                            "PROCESS_NAME": "CASTING",
                            "MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE": [532]
                        }
                    ],
                    "LOCATION_ON_TOOL": [90,100]
                },
                {
                    "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                        {
                            "PROCESS_NAME": "CASTING",
                            "MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE": [532, 900]
                        }
                    ],
                    "LOCATION_ON_TOOL": [20,3]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "PART_ID": "AA",
            "MATERIAL": "CARBON PLATE",
            "GRADE": "A",
            "DIMENSION": [
                {
                    "LENGTH_S": 17,
                    "WIDTH": 10
                }
            ],
            "PARAMETER": [
                {
                    "MEASUREMENT_DATA": [
                        {
                            "PROCESS_NAME": "STAMPING",
                            "MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE": [301]
                        }
                    ],
                    "LOCATION_ON_TOOL": [20,3]
                }
            ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you "Later I'll post my code that didn't work" then it just looks like you're trying to get others to write the code for you. Please [edit] your question with what you have already tried.

Comment: I’m in hurry now. I’ll write it within 12 hours

Comment: I’ve found the logic. I’ll post it here later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussed with my team, I figured out the solution.

```
grouped_data_1=df.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE').agg(collect_set(struct('MACHINE_NAME','DATE_TIME','PROCESS')).alias('MANUFACTURE'))

grouped_data_2=df.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE').agg(collect_set(struct('LENGTH_S','WIDTH')).alias('DIMENSION'))

grouped_data_3=df.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','LOCATION_ON_TOOL','PROCESS_NAME').agg(collect_set('MATERIAL_TEMPERATURE').alias('MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE'))

grouped_data_3=grouped_data_3.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','LOCATION_ON_TOOL').agg(collect_set(struct('PROCESS_NAME','MEASUREMENT_TEMPERATURE')).alias('MEASUREMENT_DATA'))

grouped_data_3=grouped_data_3.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE').agg(collect_set(struct('LOCATION_ON_TOOL','MEASUREMENT_DATA')).alias('PARAMETER'))

join_grouped_data=grouped_data_3.join(grouped_data_2,['PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE']).join(grouped_data_1,['PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD','PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE'])

grouped_data_4=join_grouped_data.groupBy('PROD_ID','PROD_NAME', 'USAGE', 'TYPE_PROD').agg(collect_set(struct('PART_ID','MATERIAL', 'GRADE','MANUFACTURE','DIMENSION','PARAMETER')).alias('PARTS'))
```

I didn't write line how to export the JSON file, since it can find from other question & answer.